# Google Sheets - How to write value of a cell if a word is found in a row

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a question about what code am I supposed to use for one automatic function.

Basically, what I am trying to do is:

If `value` (for example, text `John`) found in a `cell` (for example, cell `B3`) then write value of cell `A3` to the cell with this function.

So, let's say I have a sheet structured like this:

```
A1 = John, B1 = Location;

A3 = Somewhere, B3 = List of Workers, including 'John'
A4 = Everywhere, B4 = List of Workers
A5 = Away, B5 = List of Workers, including 'John'
```

I would want the cell `B1` to search if, from `B3` to `B5`, it can find `John` in the cells' text.

If it does, add the value of `X1` (where X is the row letter where it was found) into `A2` - otherwise don't.

In the end, `A2` would look like this:

> Somewhere, Away

in this example's case.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do, have a look in the formula to see if it works the way you intended.

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(A1,B3),A3),"")&IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(A1,B4),A4),"")&IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(A1,B5),A5),"")
```

To remove the last comma, you may do the formula in another cell, say E5. then use `=LEFT(E5, LEN(E5)-1)`